Specified resources aren't being sent to SLURM when running snakemage
I'm trying to run a snakemake v8 workflow where the entire project needs to be completed on a SLURM cluster, but one rule needs to be run on a GPU partition, while the others are executed on CPU nodes. I specify the default partition in my config file, which works fine, but when it tries to execute the GPU rule, I get the following error from SLURM:
WorkflowError:
SLURM job submission failed. The error message was sbatch: error: You must request a gpu using the --gpus or --gres option to use gpu_test partition, if you have CPU work for this hardware please use test
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Unspecified error

I've tried specifying my resources with gpus, gres, and simply gpu (as indicated in the snakemake documentation, and get the same error regardless.
resources:
        slurm_partition="gpu_test",
        gpus=1,
        # gres="gpu:1",
        # gres="gpu:nvidia_a100_1g.10gb:1",

When I look at my log files, it seems like snakemake is requesting nodes on the cluster first? I'm not sure what's going on or how to fix it.
How do I ensure snakemake passes the necessary arguments to SLURM?

Can you add your snakemake version and how you are interacting with slurm?

try this slurm_extra: "'--gpus=1'". i wrestled with this months ago. ended up creating slurm profile and running snakemake with --workflow-profile <path_to_slurm_profile>

In snakemake v8 the easiest way (at the time of writing) appears to be to install the slurm executor plugin in your environment:
pip install snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm
conda install -c bioconda snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm

Then you create a profile that defines parameters for the submission script to use. If you don't have one yet, you can for example create the default profile which is always automatically used: profiles/default/config.yaml
executor: slurm

default-resources:
  slurm_partition="some_dpartition_name",

If you need different settings for a particular rule, like in your case, you add to the profile:
set-resources:
    my_gpu_rule:
        slurm_partition: "gpu_test"
        slurm_extra: "'---gres=gpu:1'"

I haven't tried this myself, so it might not work immediately, but it should set you on the path. See docs and Github issues for further inspiration and please share whether it worked or not:

https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-plugin-catalog/plugins/executor/slurm.html
https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2701
https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm/issues/18

